# DecimalUpDown (Extended WPF toolkit) - Source only gets updated on lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Extended WPF toolkit's DecimalUpDown control with its Value property binded to a Decimal? as follows:

```
   <extToolkit:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding BlahBlah, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ShowButtonSpinner="False" />

private Decimal? blahblah = 5;
    public Decimal? BlahBlah
    {
        get { return blahblah; }
        set { blahblah = value; }
    }
```

I noticed that as I key in the number in the textbox, the Value does not get updated until I click outside the control. Its ValueChanged event is not fired as well until I click outside.

I intend for the value to be updated as soon as the user changes the Value (i.e. real-time). Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: I was going to say that you should set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` but you already did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your binding parameter "gets lost" in the value transitions. The `NumericUpDown` controls internally bind a `WatermarkTextBox` to the `Text` property via `TemplateBinding`, to have the control respect your UpdateSourceTrigger it would probably need to be applied at that level. So due to this intermediate binding and the non-immediate synching between `Value` and `Text` you cannot control the source-update-behavior.

Comment: This is correct. Currently the Value will only be updated on LostFocus or when the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: I suppose there is nothing I can do about this. Can anybody recommend another WPF component (free or commercial) that can fulfill my requirements?

Comment: You can download the source code and implement your required functionality.

Comment: @BrianLagunas Just stumbled over this problem too. You should at least add a description of this behavior to the codeplex site. Otherwise i'd expect the _UpdateSourceTrigger_ to work like on every other control. Also its very problematic because sometimes LostFocus doesn't get called at all (when pressing a button on the ribbon for example)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to replace the control template, with one that has the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.
I did this last year by copying the existing template, making the change, then using it in my control.
New Resource:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="newDecimalUpDownTemplate" 
                     TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <extToolkit:ButtonSpinner x:Name="Spinner" 
                                  AllowSpin="{Binding AllowSpin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                  IsTabStop="False" 
                                  ShowButtonSpinner="{Binding ShowButtonSpinner, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="TextBox" 
                                         AcceptsReturn="False" 
                                         BorderThickness="0" 
                                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                         ContextMenu="{TemplateBinding ContextMenu}" 
                                         Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                         FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" 
                                         FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" 
                                         FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" 
                                         FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                         FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" 
                                         HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                         MinWidth="20" 
                                         SelectAllOnGotFocus="{Binding SelectAllOnGotFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                         TextAlignment="{Binding TextAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                         TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                                         Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" 
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                         WatermarkTemplate="{Binding WatermarkTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                         Watermark="{Binding Watermark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.IsReadOnly>
                    <Binding Path="IsEditable" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:InverseBoolConverter/>
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.IsReadOnly>
            </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox>
        </extToolkit:ButtonSpinner>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

In my Control:

```
 Template="{StaticResource newDecimalUpDownTemplate}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I myself also spent some time on this problem and found a pretty nice solution, I edited the template (Right click the DecimalUpDown and go to edit template Edit Template, thanks Ben you saved me some serious time --> [How to overwrite a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661777/how-to-overwrite-a-style)) and combined it with the brilliant emorog solution!

I wrote all of this in a style:

```
<Style x:Key="DecimalUpDownStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DecimalUpDown}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DecimalUpDown}">
                    <xctk:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner" AllowSpin="{Binding AllowSpin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ButtonSpinnerLocation="{Binding ButtonSpinnerLocation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" ShowButtonSpinner="{Binding ShowButtonSpinner, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoMoveFocus="{Binding AutoMoveFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" AutoSelectBehavior="{Binding AutoSelectBehavior, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" AcceptsReturn="False" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" ContextMenu="{TemplateBinding ContextMenu}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}" IsUndoEnabled="True" MinWidth="20" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SelectAllOnGotFocus="{Binding SelectAllOnGotFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TextAlignment="{Binding TextAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" WatermarkTemplate="{Binding WatermarkTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Watermark="{Binding Watermark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </xctk:ButtonSpinner>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and am able to use it like this:

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Style="{StaticResource DecimalUpDownStyle1}" Value="{Binding DisplayValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```