# How to overwrite a style

Tags: c#, wpf

I use the DecimalUpDown control from the Extended WPF Toolkit in my WPF ModernUI app:

[image]

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding myProperty}" Increment="1"  Maximum="10" Minimum="0" />
```

What bugs me is this: If an accent color is selected, for example red, then standard ModernUI-Controls such as textboxes adapt that color nicely:

[image]

The DecimalUpDown control however sticks to its style. For example, the control is blue when it is active and the RepeatButtons used in the control do not look like ModernUI buttons:

[image]

Even worse: all TextBoxes in the View where the DecimalUpDown control is placed now exhibit this style and are highlighted in blue instead of red:

[image]

**How can I change that?**

EDIT: this is the generated ControlTemplate when I follow Ben's good advice:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <xctk:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner" AllowSpin="{Binding AllowSpin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                            ...>
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" AutoMoveFocus="{Binding AutoMoveFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                   AutoSelectBehavior="{Binding AutoSelectBehavior, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                   AcceptsReturn="False" 
                                   .../>
        </xctk:ButtonSpinner>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            ...
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

It's then possible to style the WatermarkTextBox and the ButtonSpinner:

[image]

What I have not managed so far: Is there a way to access the RepeatButtons inside the ButtonSpinner, so that I can set their styles as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s probably necessary to write your own template and define the color there. Sometimes there is no direct way to change properties which are part of the UI-element. 
Try to edit a copy of the template and search for the blue color value.
Right click the DecimalUpDown and go to edit template
[image: Edit Template]

If the color value is no set there, it´s possible it´s set via the System.Colors (e.g. ActiveBorderBrush)

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}" Color="Orange" />
```

The System.Colors define some standard behavious when a control is active, highlighted, etc. MSDN lists all existing ones: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This is great, I did not know about the "Edit Template" option. In this case, since the control itself is composed of several controls [a textbox, two repeat buttons], I cannot get access to the "child"-controls. Nevertheless, very nice!

Comment: Ben, is there a way to access the child controls from the template? I've added the template in my question. I can successfully style the "outer" element (border etc.), but e.g. the RepeatButtons inside the control, I cannot access.

Comment: Maybe you could try to add the ButtonSpinner as a seperate Element and redo the "Edit a copy" step. Then create a custom style either for all ButtonSpinners or a named one to use in your DecimalUpDown Control.

Comment: <Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}"> for instance would change all styles for the progressbar when added in the <Application.Resources>